# Recognition source of event in PyQT

Tags: python, user-interface, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I`m starting with PyQt4 and right now I have a problem with events.

I have one main class let say MainWindow. MainWindow has a list of buttons of type ButtonX (inherence form QPushButton). I would like to achieve one of 2 solutions (depends which is easier).

1) After click one of the button from the list I would like to run a one method of MainWindow. I would like to be able to read a source of event there (recognize clicked button)

2) Second solution is to run a method defined in ButtonX class.

What I tried is:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.getButton(0, 0), QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.getButton(0, 0).buttonMethod())

QtCore.QObject.connect(self.getButton(0, 0), QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.getButton(0, 0), QtCore.SLOT("incrementValue()"))
```

and even this line occure suspend Python interpreter

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.getButton(0, 0), QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.getButton(0, 0), QtCore.SLOT("incrementValue"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) After click one of the button from the list I would like to run a one method of MainWindow. I would like to be able to read a source of event there (recognize clicked button)

You can access the source of an event using [QObject.sender()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qobject.html#sender). But, as the instructions indicate, it's often better to use [QSignalMapper](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qsignalmapper.html) or do things in a more object oriented fashion.

> 2) Second solution is to run a method defined in ButtonX class.

Look carefully at what you typed for the last argument of the first connect call:

```
self.getButton(0, 0).buttonMethod()
```

The above will evaluate `getButton` with parameters `0, 0` and then, on that object, **call** the `buttonMethod` method.  So, unless `buttonMethod` returns a method, you are using the return value of `buttonMethod` as the last parameter to the connect call.  If this method returns a function, then this is just fine.

Rather, I would expect to see something like the following:

```
self.getButton(0, 0).buttonMethod # note no parenthesis at end
```

Take a look at the PyQt examples directory provided with PyQt as they'll demonstrate the exact syntax and serve as good examples.

Here's one small example:

```
class MW(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.b1 = QPushButton("Button1")
        self.b2 = QPushButton("Button2")
        layout.addWidget(self.b1)
        layout.addWidget(self.b2)
        self.connect(self.b1, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.buttonWasPressed)
        self.connect(self.b2, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.buttonWasPressed)

    def buttonWasPressed(self):
        print "button %s was pressed" % self.sender()
```

Comment: in qt4 you can use new style slots and signals, in your example it would look like:

`self.b1.clicked.connect(self.buttonWasPressed)`

Comment: I use PyQt5 and I get an error saying sender doesnt exist..is there any work around.